# Phpunit 3.6 does not find the unit test

Tags: phpunit

I get Cannot open file "FooTest.php"

I am using PHP 5.4.0 and PHPUnit 3.6 on Windows

I have traced the issue back to PHPUnit\Util\Filesystem.php when it calls get_include_path which contains "." and the location to pear.

For some reason it doesn't resolve . to where the tests are as it resolves it locally to the PHPUnit location.

How do I get phpunit to recognise the location of the tests.

Answer (score 1):

First make also sure your PHPUnit installation and all dependencies are up-to-date:

```
pear upgrade phpunit/PHPUnit --alldeps
```

In case your pear installation is messed up you can also obtain it from [the github repository](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit).

Depending on how your project and enviroment is set up make sure your current directory is your projects directory.

```
cd /your/projects/home/directory/
```

The common syntax to invoke phpunit is either

```
phpunit [switches] <your_unit_test.php>
```

or

```
phpunit [switches] <directory>
```

So, basically in case your tests are stored within directory `YourUnitTests` the easiest way to start it  would be just to use

```
phpunit YourUnitTests
```

Comment: I don't have this behaviour, but I'm currently using php 5.3 on my test enviroment. Maybe open a bug report here: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit , so the dev can take a look at this behaviour.